# Applet to find least-crossings drawing for an input graph

Tags: graph-theory, math-software, visualization

Is there a convenient online applet that allows me to draw a graph, after which it outputs a plane drawing of an isomorphic graph that has (approximately) the least number of crossings among all drawings of the graph?

I have this *small* graph whose drawing I would like to simplify, and it would be great if I could label the vertices with names.

Comment: I don't think you mean a planar graph. Planar graphs are graphs that can be drawn on the plane with no crossings.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but even computing the crossing number of a graph (let alone finding an embedding with that many crossings) is an NP-hard problem, so if there is such a program, it likely only works on small graphs, or just gives drawings with number of crossings within a small percentage of the optimum.

Comment: That's ok, I have a small graph which I would like to merely simplify and make it easier to comprehend, so even approximate answers are fine.

Comment: For a single small graph, put it into a vector program and start moving the vertices around.  See the puzzle game Planarity.

Comment: Well by "small" I mean 19 vertices and 33 edges, so it's not exactly easy to do it intuitively. I seem to have hit a local minimum with my manipulation, but I have a feeling that it can be simplified much more.

Comment: This is not online app, but I think Maple and Mathematica both have good graph drawing tools.